# simple loop with append in Python

Tags: python, loops, append

I want to get a loop, so instead of writing me code such:

```
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([ data[0]['body'] , data[1]['body'] , data[2]['body'] , data[3]['body'] ....  ])
```

I get it in a loop. So far I have tried:

```
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([ append(data[i]['body']) , data[i+1]['body']) ])
```

Any idea on how to make it work? I get the following error:

> name 'append' is not defined

Comment: `append()` must be called on a list, it doesn't exist as a global scope function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to extract the 'body' content from the json data and have a list of text elements to then pass it to the feature extractor (make sure you have preprocessed the text before).

Try this:

```
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([d['body'] for d in data])
```

Or, if it is more clear to you, you can create the list first and then pass it to the function:

```
bodies = [d['body'] for d in data]
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(bodies)
```

Hope it helps :)

Happy coding !!!

P.D: I haven't tested the code, but I think the idea is clear.

Comment: great answer @Salias ! I looks really good, wha tod you mean by processes the text before?

Comment: If you want to extract tf-idf matrix of your collection, you should have been removed stopwords, punctuation, etc.... before. Otherwise, you will have a very noisy matrix with meaningless words like "to" or "and" as the most repeated, and thus, the most important. The pre-processing filters depend on the task you want to accomplish. Have a look at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273127322_Preprocessing_Techniques_for_Text_Mining

Answer (score 1):

You need to call append() on a list. eg MyList.append(element)

Comment: true, I tried to define a list before but the vectorizer.fit_transform does not allow it.... any other alternatives?